# get access to getJSON objects values

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have an JSON object of posts:

```
{

  "how-to-create-a-blog": {
    "post-url": "blog/how-to-create-a-blog.html",
    "post-image": "/posts/post-image.jpg",
    "post-title": "How to create a blog"
  },

  "how-to-create-a-mega-menu": {
    "post-url": "blog/how-to-create-a-mega-menu.html",
    "post-image": "/posts/post-image.jpg",
    "post-title": "How to create a mega menu"
  },

  "what-is-wordpress": {
    "post-url": "blog/what-is-wordpress.html",
    "post-image": "/posts/post-image.jpg",
    "post-title": "What is WordPress"
  },

  "create-your-first-wordpress-theme": {
    "post-url": "blog/create-your-first-wordpress-theme.html",
    "post-image": "/posts/post-image.jpg",
    "post-title": "Create your first wordpress theme"
  }

}
```

the JSON object structure is:

```
{

  "post-id": {
    "post-url": "",
    "post-image": "",
    "post-title": ""
  }

}
```

I need to count number of post with jQuery `length` but it gives `undefined` error.

```
  $.getJSON('/all-posts.json', function(data) {
   var postNumbers = data[0];

    console.log(postNumbers.length);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` property can be used to count the number of elements of a JS array. Here you have a JS Object. So we have to convert it into an array of its keys and take its `length`

by

```
Object.keys(postNumbers).length
```

Here is the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it with lots of examples and info regarding browser support.

#### reply to comments

for older browsers that doesnt support `Object.keys` ,

you can define the function manually. like

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function (obj) {
        var keys = [],
            k;
        for (k in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
}
```

#### if you want to count the number of unique urls in the `JSON object`

```
var uniqueURLS = [];
for (x in sample) {

    if(typeof(sample[x]["post-url"]) != "undefined" && sample[x]["post-url"] != null && uniqueURLS.indexOf(sample[x]["post-url"])==-1) {

        uniqueURLS.push(sample[x]["post-url"]);

    }

}

alert("there were "+uniqueURLS.length+" unique urls in there");
```

Here is [**a demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeE5y/).

Comment: Thanks in worked, can you tell me how to count all post-urls?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. no need to answer. I see that this feature is for ie9+, how about olders?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, is there any way to get every inner objects like data[1], by this I mean data["how-to-create-a-blog"]. When I try with names it works but it does not work with numbers. any solutions?

Comment: You cant access because its not a js array now but a js object. But u can loop overt the object and make an array out of it. Like we did for counting the urls.